# Is there a way to search by string previews in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I have a class which contains alot of string resources. I would like to search (Ctrl + F) particular string preview. For example

```
getString(R.string.transfer_label);
```

which is shown in intellij IDEA as string resources value

```
"TRANSFER"
```

So when i press CTRL+F and type "TRANSFER" naturally nothing happens. Is there any other shortcut that allows it? or any existing plugin?

Edit: I am looking for solution which works like CTRL+F one. I mean you type in something and it instantly moves you to place in code where its used. Making it very quick.

Comment: you want to find "transfer" word in your project?

Comment: no i want to find "TRANSFER" occurance in this particular class, but there is no any "TRANSFER" string in it. Only R.string.transfer_label which is shown as "TRANSFER" thanks to intellij string previews. So i wonder if is there any way for searching through those string previews

Answer (score 0):

I normally go in my strings.xml and use "Find usage" (Alt + F7) on a string resource. This is the only way I know.

Comment: I know it can be done this way. But you have to go into string resources first. I am looking for simplier and quicker way for doing this.

Comment: @PhateeP You can directly also search  just select `R.string.transfer_label` and then `Alt+F7`.

Comment: that is not what i want to do. Imagine situation when you noticed that there is wrong logic applied for dislplaying particular string so you go into Activity and type string name to quickly find a place where its used, but u cant find it since its in string resources. So you have to do those additional steps you are talking about

Comment: Well, technically you are using a string resource in your code. So your search term just isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

If your key Map is Default- cntrl+shift+F

**If you want change the keys and key maps go here**

Android Studio -> File ->Settings > KeyMap

**Please find the below image for reference :**

[image]

You can search in search bar what you are looking for

Comment: it works but is also not what i am searching for. First of all you have to type name of string then find right occurance and go into file. When you are in class that you know string occurs, you can click CTRL + F and when u type anything it instantly moves you to place in code where its used. Just by simple typing

Comment: Use ctrl+F3 if you know the word to find at next occurrence and moreover you can search in search bar what you are exactly looking for using key words.